# "may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]"

Tags: c++

I would like to ask a question that make me confuse. I am trying so scan string and covert that into real number. Using that number to calculate value. Here is my code:

```
string input_file_name1 = "shen_test_38_30_60__78_26_38_b_100_ch1-533.0-mhz-8000.0-ksps-2016-06-20-17.24.19-utc.dat";

string input_file_name2 = "shen_test_38_30_60__78_26_38_b_100_ch2-533.0-mhz-8000.0-ksps-2016-06-20-17.24.19-utc.dat";

std::ifstream input1(input_file_name1.c_str() , std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
std::ifstream input2(input_file_name2.c_str() , std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);

split(input_file_name1, '-', v);

for(unsigned i=1; i < v.size(); i++)
{
    if(v[i] == "mhz"){
        f_0 = atoi(v[i-1].c_str())*1e6;                 
    }

    if(v[i] == "ksps"){
        f_s = atoi(v[i-1].c_str()) * 1e3;// f_s = 8e6;          
    }
}

double nblocks;  //f_s = 8e6;

nblocks = floor(10 / (262144 / f_s));
```

when I compile I got this message:

" warning: ‘f_s’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]  nblocks = (10 / (nsamps / f_s));"

Do you have any ideal to help me fix this problem?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

That means that if `v[i]` is neither "mhz" nor "ksps", then the code that assigns something to `f_s` is never executed and therefore leaving `f_s` uninitialized.

You can prevent this warning for example like this:

```
for(unsigned i=1; i < v.size(); i++)
{
    if(v[i] == "mhz"){
        f_0 = atoi(v[i-1].c_str())*1e6;                 
    }
    else if(v[i] == "ksps"){
        f_s = atoi(v[i-1].c_str()) * 1e3;// f_s = 8e6;          
    }
    else
    {
      // v[i] is none of the expected values
       f_s = -1;  
       ... take more action
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: there is a possibility that `f_0` is not initialized, for the same reason.

Comment: Additionally, the value of `f_s` may be zero, if it is not intialized. In that case a division by zero will be attempted in the last line (`nblocks = floor(10 / (262144 / f_s));`). This may or may not trigger a segmentation fault, but it is definitely not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that `if(v[i] == "ksps")` may never be true.  If it is not then `f_s` never gets a value set to it.  What you can do is default initialize `f_s` with some value.  Then you at least know the variable has some known state.

Do note that if you have not intialized `f_0` you will have the same issue with it.