# may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

Tags: c++

I need help regarding to this message: " warning: ‘f_0’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]"

I have a file name: "shen_test_38_30_60__78_26_38_b_100_ch1-683.0-mhz-8000.0-ksps-2016-06-20-17.24.19-utc.dat";

and I want to get a values: "683" and "8000" by using scan and convert string to number, such as:

```
void split(const string& s, char c, vector<string>& v) {
   string::size_type i = 0;
   string::size_type j = s.find(c);

   while (j != string::npos) {
      v.push_back(s.substr(i, j-i));
      i = ++j;
      j = s.find(c, j);

      if (j == string::npos){
         v.push_back(s.substr(i, s.length()));
      }
   }
}
int main()
{
     string input_file_name1 = "shen_test_38_30_60__78_26_38_b_100_ch1-683.0-mhz-8000.0-ksps-2016-06-20-17.24.19-utc.dat";
     split(input_file_name1, '-', v);

            for(double i=1; i < v.size(); i++)
            {
                if(v[i] == "mhz"){
                    f_0 = atoi(v[i-1].c_str())*1e6;                 cout <<"***f_0      = " << f_0 << endl;
                }
                if(v[i] == "ksps"){
                    f_s = atoi(v[i-1].c_str()) * 1e3;               cout << "***f_s         = " <<f_s <<endl ;
                }

            }
}
```

double t1 = f_s + 10000;
double t2 = f_0 + 53000000;

it really give me a real number but when I try to do some calculation, it showed the error message: "warning: ‘f_0’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]"

any ideal , please help!

Thank you.

Comment: Show the exact code that gives that error.

Comment: Please show us [mcve]. I don't see `f_0` being defined anywhere in the code that you posted.

Comment: You need to declare the variables before using them.

Comment: This is a duplicate, you asked this question last week:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491786/may-be-used-uninitialized-in-this-function-wmaybe-uninitialized

Can you please clarify how you are declaring f_0 and v?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing how you are declaring f_0 and v, I cannot guarantee this is your issue.  However, the warning maybe-uninitialized comes from the compiler not being able to ensure that a variable has valid data before being used.  This means that even though you have f_0 being set to an actual value inside of an if statement, the compiler cannot guarantee that if statement will be hit, and that variable will be defined hence the "maybe".

The 2 possible places where f_0 can be skipped from having valid data is:

```
1.    for(double i=1; i < v.size(); i++)
2.    if(v[i] == "mhz")
```

in the case of the first, there is no guarantee that i = 1 is actually less then v.size().

In the case of the second, this is no guarantee to the compiler that v[i] will eventually contains "mhz".  With both of these circumstances in place the compiler will see that as a variable that maybe unitialized.  Even though you are hardcoding the value the compiler isn't going to check your hardcoded variables to see if they will guarantee this will be hit.

In order to avoid this warning you will have to initialize f_0 to a value.  based off of:

```
f_0 = atoi(v[i-1].c_str())
```

I will assume its an integer, so wherever you have it defined you can change the declaration to:

```
int f_0 = -1;
```

This should remove that warning, however I highly recommend using a value to can error check for as your default before attempting to use it.

Additional reading on warnings:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
void split(const string& s, char c, vector<string>& v) {
   string::size_type i = 0;
   string::size_type j = s.find(c);

   while (j != string::npos) {
      v.push_back(s.substr(i, j-i));
      i = ++j;
      j = s.find(c, j);

      if (j == string::npos){
         v.push_back(s.substr(i, s.length()));
      }
   }
}
int main()
{
     string input_file_name1 = "shen_test_38_30_60__78_26_38_b_100_ch1-683.0-mhz-8000.0-ksps-2016-06-20-17.24.19-utc.dat";
     std::vector<std::string> v;
     split(input_file_name1, '-', v);

    for(double i=1; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        if(v[i] == "mhz"){
            int f_0 = atoi(v[i-1].c_str())*1e6;                 cout <<"***f_0      = " << f_0 << endl;
        }
        if(v[i] == "ksps"){
            int f_s = atoi(v[i-1].c_str()) * 1e3;               cout << "***f_s         = " <<f_s <<endl ;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That will remove the issue of it being uninitialized but based off of his previous question last week, he needs access to both f_0 and f_s after the for loop.